# How can i use end= " " with in the function?

Tags: python

`print(x,end= "")` is working but I want to use `end= ""` in the function so `return(x,end= "")` didn't work. How can i use it in the function in this code?

```
def b(a):
   for i in a.split():
      return(i[0],end= "")
b("welcome to the jungle")
```

`wttj` is what i want.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: first characters in sentence 'wttj' . I want to return it in one line

Comment: What is your intention in returning `end=""` ? Do you want the calling code to use that somehow?

Comment: If i dont use `end=""` its return each characters in new line. I want to return it in one line

Comment: @HerpesQwe you can iterate over the splitted sentence list and get the first char of each element, later join the list back to make a string. Does the answer posted below helps?

Comment: `wtjj` appears to be a typo, please fix, it's confusing

Answer (score 3):

Using `split()` with list comprehension:

```
sentence = "welcome to the jungle"
splitted = sentence.split()
letters = [word[0] for word in splitted]
print ("".join(letters))
```

one-liner:

```
print("".join([word[0] for word in sentence.split()]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
wttj
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can only return a value once, so because you put your return statement inside the for-loop, the function only got the chance to iterate once. Try this:

```
def b(a):
    c = ''
    for i in a.split():
        c += i[0]
    return c

print(b("welcome to the jungle"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`end` is a parameter specific the `print` function, not something you can apply to an arbitrary string expression.

If you want the first letter of each word, it's just

```
def b(a):
    return ''.join(i[0] for i in a.split())
```